# How i decrypt my password using EncryptionAlgorithm(sunbeen_V1)

Tags: java

I encrypt my password using this syntax in java
EncryptionAlgorithm algorithm =  EncryptionAlgorithmFactory.getEncryptionAlgorithm(EncryptionAlgorithmFactory.SUNBEEN_V1);
String encryptedPassword = algorithm.encrypt(password);
Input : 123
output in encrypted : QL0AFWMIX8NRZauqi4sKCKuhiiIynqH/XF7L277vIQGDCwgjAQCpAA==.

my question is how i decrypt my password using SUNBEEN_V1 
i also search in google sunbeen_V1 did not get any search result.

Any Idea regarding sunbeen_V1.

thanks.

Comment: Even your question looks somewhat encrypted...

Comment: Now Gyro check again ..

Comment: What's the point of encrypting if you can just uncrypt it without a password? You've a concept error there.

Comment: My point is that can any body know about SunBeen_V1 or SunbeenEncryption.

Comment: And everyone knows about SHA256. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: sir I want to decrypt my password but i use this MD5,SHA1,and SHA256 but my password was encrypted in sunbeen_V1 so i can decrypt on in sunbeen_v1 only no others algorithms is used so i want to know about what is sunbeen_V1 and where is located.

Comment: What library are you using? The only references to `EncryptionAlgorithmFactory` I can find are for some .NET library. Is SUNBEEN_v1 an *encryption* algorithm, or a *hashing* algorithm? With how you use it, it looks like a hash and not encryption.

Comment: You should provide a little more context - neither "EncryptionAlgorithmFactory" nor "SUNBEEN_v1" seems to be well known names in Java...

Comment: You shouldn't be encrypting passwords at all. You should be hashing them.

Comment: I am using Common.jar inside common.jar there is class inside this jar  com.sunbeen.api.common.security 1) EncryptionAlgorithm.class 2) EncryptionAlgorithmFactory.class and another one is inside com.sunbeen.common.security 1) SunbeenEncryption.class ---kitsune

Comment: I can't say anything about SunBeen_V1, but passwords are often encrypted with a trapdoor algorythm: it can be encrypted but never decrypted.  For passwords, you don't need to decrypt.  All you want to know is that someone gave you the same password as the original, so you ENCRYPT the new supplied password, and simply see if the encrypted result is the same.